# How do I use For Loop twice to find datatable columns and rows?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I want to use for loop to get average of datatable columns and rows. What I want to do is that what if there are 100 ~ 1000 columns and rows, I can't keep on adding them in the code. is there one simple code that can get average of automatically as I add columns and rows?

here is my code, I am stuck I don't know what to write in ?? area below and this code gets me error please help...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtGrid = gridData.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
        Math columnIndex = new Math();

        List<double> avgList = new List<double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dtGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {

            for (int k = 1; k < dtGrid.Rows.Count; k++)
            {
                // ??
                avgList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dtGrid.Rows[i].ToString()));
            }

        }
        //this is from other class name Math
        /* public double getAverageValue(List<double> avgList)
        {
            double averageList = 0;

            averageList = MathNet.Numerics.Statistics.Statistics.Mean(avgList.ToList());

            return averageList;
        }*/ 
        double averageX1 = columnIndex.getAverageValue(avgList);

        List<Math> list = new List<Math>();

        //using get; set from other class 
        list.Add(new Math { Result = "Average", X1 = averageX1.ToString() });

        gridData2.DataSource = list;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What is your question exactly? Do you want to calculate Average of values of a column? Or do you want to calculate Average of values of all cells together? Or something else?

Comment: I want to average up each columns not caulculate them into one. so if I have 10 columns I want to have them show individually. so 10 answer show be show up. I have checkboxes in each of first rows so I need to average up from row 1 instead of 0 thats why I need to use for loop not foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your loop is inside out.  Try this:

```
DataTable dtGrid = gridData.DataSource as DataTable;
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
Math columnIndex = new Math();

List<double> avgList = new List<double>();
for (int k = 1; k < dtGrid.Rows.Count; k++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dtGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        // ??
        avgList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dtGrid.Rows[k].Columns[i].ToString()));
    }
}
```

This logic averages all columns in a row together.  If you need,, you can create a Dictionary and average each column separately.  Something like thisL

```
Dictionary<int, List<double>> AvgColumnList = new Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.List<double>>();
```

This uses a dictionary that contains a list for each column in the row.  If there are 100 columns, then there will be 100 entries in the dictionary with index 0 - 99.  Each dictionary item will contain a list of doubles.

```
for (int k = 1; k < dtGrid.Rows.Count; k++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dtGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!AvgColumnList.Keys.Contains(i))
            AvgColumnList.Add(i, new List<double>());

        AvgColumnList[i].Add(Convert.ToDouble(dtGrid.Rows[k].Columns[i].ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am trying to use for loop because I have check boxes in first rows, right below headers columns. so that I need to average up from the second rows instead of zero .
for example for(int i = 1; i < dtGrid.Rows.Count; i++ ) if I use foreach loop I can't control which rows to start. sorry that I didn't mentioned it earlier.. are you able to show me in for loop too?

Comment: Thank you!! it helps but my columns[i] get error so I used avgList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dtGrid.Rows[k][i].ToString()));

um.. 1 more question. with this I only get 1 column result, what if I have 100 of columns to calculate? I can't keep on adding avglist1, avglist2, is there a way to calculate many columns individually? with 1 avgList in seperate columns?

Answer (score 0):

DataTable is zero index based, in your code row count started from `1` it should be `0`, also `dtGrid.Rows[i]` is a row not the cell value. Use below code to loop through each cell of a `DataTable`

**Update :** Code updated as OP want to save each column data separately and irrespective of column numbers.

```
 List<List<double>> perColumnAvg = new List<List<double>>();

 for (int i = 0; i < dtGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
 {
     avgList = new List<double>();
     for (int k = 0; k < dtGrid.Rows.Count; k++)
     {
         // ??
         avgList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dtGrid.Rows[k][i].ToString()));
     }
     perColumnAvg.Add(avgList);
 }
```

Now you can compute individual column average as

```
foreach (var columnList in perColumnAvg)
{
    // place your logic here.
    columnIndex.getAverageValue(columnList);
}
```

And can compute avg across table using.

```
double tableAvg = columnIndex.getAverageValue(perColumnAvg.SelectMany(s=>s));
```

Comment: Thank you!! this help but I have 1 more question, with this I only get 1 column result, what if I have 100 of columns to calculate? I can't keep on adding avglist1, avglist2, is there a way to calculate many columns individually? with 1 avgList in seperate columns?

Comment: We can do that, it's very easy.

Comment: Define `List<List<double>` and store individual column values.